# Opencart 1.5.5.1 categories images on homepage

Tags: image, opencart, categories

I've add module "categories" to homepage, and now I see categories list with numer of products on homepage but can't see category thumbs.

in file: /public_html/catalog/view/theme/MY-THEME/template/module/category.tpl I found around line 10:

`<a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>`

and I think sommewhere there I also should add something like: category['thumb'] to display image before category name but do I have to add something in controller files, I soppouse yes but need help here.

I thing i should define $category['thumb'] in controller but how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in saying that you need to edit the controller file for this module, you need to add the model that gets the image for that category as well as get the image for any child categories. So there are two edits you need to make, first to the controller file

Open the catalog/controller/module/category.php & find this line:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

Now you need to add the model so that you can get the image data from the DB, add this line **below** it:

```
$this->load->model('tool/image');
```

Now find this line, it will be in the `foreach` loop:

```
$children = $this->model_catalog_category>getCategories($category['category_id']);
```

Add the following **above** the line:

```
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category>getCategory($category['category_id']);       

if ($category_info['image']) {
    $image = $category_info['image'];
} else {
    $image = '';
}
```

You also need to do this for the child categories, find this line in the next `foreach` loop:

```
$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);
```

Add this directly **below** it:

```
$child_info = $this->model_catalog_category>getCategory($child['category_id']);     

if ($child_info['image']) {
    $child_image = $child_info['image'];
} else {
    $child_image = '';
}
```

At the moment we now have two variables that contain the image paths: `$image` and `$child_image`, these need to be passed to the template file, you can do so by editing the two arrays that are created. We'll do the child array first as that is almost directly below the last edit you made. Find this line in the `children_data` array:

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
```

Add a comma to the end of the line and paste this line directly below it:

```
'image'       => $child_image
```

Now we add the image to the `$category` array, find this line and add a comma to the end as with the last step:

```
'href'        => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
```

The next step is obvious now, add the following line directly below it:

```
'image'       => $image
```

Now you should note that the template file can access a new variable $image when in the `foreach` loops. I'll leave the rest to you as you'd know how and where you'd like to display the image. The code below will generate an image if it's used in the `foreach` loop of either the Category:

```
<img src="<?php echo $category['image']; ?>
```

Or this can be used for a child category:

```
<img src="<?php echo $child['image']; ?>
```